# Como utilizar Captcha Google en 2 formularios dentro del mismo html? Uno de estos form se ve en Desktop y otro en Mobile. Nunca al mismo tiempo

Tags: html, captcha

Tengo 2 form con distinto diseño ya que uno es para desktop y otro para mobile pero comparten el mismo html y el captcha me funciona solo para uno de ellos.
De que manera puedo resolverlo? el hidden y el display none para esta situación no sirve. Tambien probe cargarlos mediante `include` pero es lo mismo cuando lo imprime en el html solo toma el captcha para uno solo.
Espero que puedan ayudarme.
Muchas gracias!

```html
<!-- desktop -->
<div class="hidden-xs">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-cntct" placeholder="Mail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="------Site key-----"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" value="Send" class="center-block">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- mobile -->
<div class="visible-xs">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control input-cntct" placeholder="Mail" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="------Site key-----"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" value="Send" class="center-block">Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: después de mucho tiempo tengo el mismo problema con la v2 invisible. La solución seria la misma? no estoy logrando que funcionen los dos formularios

Answer (score 1):

1. Añadimos la capa que contiene el recaptcha dentro de cada formulario, asignando a cada capa uno un id diferente:

Creas un div por cada id y cada uno estos lo pones en su correspondiente formulario

id="recaptcha1"
 id="recaptcha2"

2. Cargas la librería JavaScript de Google y algo de Javascript

```
<script>
  var recaptcha1;
  var recaptcha2;
  var myCallBack = function() {

    recaptcha1 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha1', {
      'sitekey' : '6Lc_0f4SABBBAF9ZA', //Reemplazar esto por la Key de tu sitio
      'theme' : 'light'
    });

    recaptcha2 = grecaptcha.render('recaptcha2', {
      'sitekey' : '6Lc_0f4SABBBAF9ZA',  //Reemplazar esto por la Key de tu sitio
      'theme' : 'dark'
    });
  };
</script>
```

Con esto te debería funcionar

Fuente: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/webmaster-es/fm7to1oovdk;context-place=forum/webmaster-es

Comment: y para obtener el valor de cada uno de éstos?
siempre me toma el valor del primero.